# WEKA classification using embeddings

Tags: weka

Currently I have been working on code snippet classification using Code2vec models which I have trained on a set of python code snippet, my idea was to produce embeddings for each code snippet and attach the label to it and use it further for the final classification for instance the arff file for weka will look like the following:

```
relation XYZ 

@Attributes @Class@ {buggy,non_buggy}
@Attributes index1 real 
.........
.........
.........
.........
.........
@Attributes index380 real

@data

buggy, 0.28600096702575684, -0.03643874451518059, -0.06801733374595642,.......
..................
..................
..................
non_buggy, 0.4966501295566559, -0.38083720207214355, -0.378182053565979,.......
```

For the classification, I split my full dataset into 80% for training and 20% for testing using the  percentage split option provided by WEKA. I got a precision of 99% I was surprised though I tried to do other splits for instance 1% for training and 99% for testing however the performance  is still good almost 99% precision which I found not logic in this case.

do I have to change anything before the second split ? does anybody have experienced this issue while working with embeddings in WEKA?

Comment: What is the distribution of the two class labels? If one of the labels makes up 99% of the instances, then the model only needs to predict this label, giving you an accuracy of 99%. BTW The correct ARFF format is `@attribute ` and not `@Attributes ` and `@relation ` and not `relation`.